# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1 BOX ' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

This only happens when I Union a Select statement from a View (which works fine on its own), with a Select statement which is hard-coded to return a specific row.

```
Select * From View
UNION ALL
Select 'text' as Col1, 'text1' as Col2
```

This is just to give you an idea of what I am doing.

Both statements work just fine when run independently.

Thank you!

Comment: Are View's columns text or integers? (Must be matching data types...)

Comment: It matches the first two columns from the view which apparently aren't varchar but int with your two hardcoded varchars.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly convert the types in the first part of the `union`:

```
select cast(col1 as varchar(255)) as col1, cast(col2 as varchar(255) as col2
from view
union all
select 'text', 'tex1';
```

As sort-of explained in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026(v=sql.110).aspx):

> Is a query specification or query expression that returns data to be
>   combined with the data from another query specification or query
>   expression. The definitions of the columns that are part of a UNION
>   operation do not have to be the same, but they must be compatible
>   through implicit conversion. When data types differ, the resulting
>   data type is determined based on the rules for data type precedence.
>   When the types are the same but differ in precision, scale, or length,
>   the result is determined based on the same rules for combining
>   expressions. For more information, see Precision, Scale, and Length
>   (Transact-SQL).

I'm the first to admit that this isn't 100% clear.  But, the type precedence rules mean that SQL Server prefers numeric types over character types and hence you can get conversion problems.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in the view I had several non-numeric values in one numeric column. I wasn't explicitly setting the data type for this column and SQL was handling it on its own so I wasn't aware of the situation.

It was only becoming an issue when the second part of the union returned a numeric value in the same column.

I had to review the data line by line to realize where the problem was.